# how to constuct n-ary tree by scala

Tags: scala, tree, functional-programming

I recently want to retreive data from mysql and use it to form a n-ary. Because I use scala to develop my app,so I want to program in a functional style,without any mutable state.

Here is my code:

```
case class TreeNode(id: String, parentId:String, lable: String, 
                    children: Option[Seq[TreeNode]] = None)
private def buildTree: TreeNode = { 
    // todo build a tree like following from a Seq[TreeNode] queryied
    // from mysql by Slick TreeNode("0","-1", "menu1", Some(List(TreeNode("1","0" 
 }
```

Comment: "I want to do a homework assignment"? Anyway, sounds a reasonable thing to do. What's stopping you? What's your question? Please show us what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: here is my code:
  case class TreeNode(id: String, parentId:String, lable: String, children:  Option[Seq[TreeNode]] = None)

  private def buildTree: TreeNode = {
    //todo build a tree like following from a Seq[TreeNode] queryied from mysql  by Slick
    TreeNode("0","-1", "menu1", Some(List(TreeNode("1","0" ,"menu2", Some(List(TreeNode("2", "1","menu3"), TreeNode("3","1" ,"menu4")))))))
  },and I'am stuck by todo.

Comment: So, you've not really tried anything yet. SO isn't a site where people write your code for you. Please at least explain how you were thinking of writing buildTree, and maybe provide a complete example query result. Edit your question to do this, it won't fit in a comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your own implementation n-ary tree.

Scala collections has no class to deal with it.